# Set variable with Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Super quick question as I'm getting used to arrow functions. I know they implicitly return, and that we can implicitly return as long as its an expression. However, for example, can I reduce the following 
`$scope.setEdit = () => { $scope.edit = true; }`
to 
`$scope.setEdit = () => $scope.edit = true;`
without encountering any undesired behavior? I'm unsure how arrow functions behave when simply assigning a variable. I've only used in place where I normally would have a return statement, never with simple assignment.

This is just an example. Thanks!

Comment: Does any code use the return value?

Comment: This has little to do with arrow functions, but with expression evaluation. Whatever the expression evaluates to (with possible side effects) will be the returned value. So if you know what the expression `a = b` does and returns, then you have your answer.

Comment: "I know they implicitly return"  - no they don't.  They only do this when you omit the curly braces.  `myFunc = () => { a = b + c }` will return `undefined`, but `myFunc = () =>  a = b + c;` will return the new value of `a`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, guys. This is clear to me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has little to do with arrow functions, but with expression evaluation. Whatever the expression evaluates to (with possible side effects) will be the returned value.

This arrow-expression function:

```
() => a = b
```

does and returns the same as:

```
() => {
    return a = b;
}
```

It is a function with side effects: `a` gets a value. Assignments can occur in expressions and return the assigned value. So it is equivalent to:

```
() => {
    a = b;
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a misunerstanding of how arrow functions work.  They only implicitly return when you use the shorthand version.

Here's what I mean - these three function are functionally identical, they all return the string `'hello'`

```js
function a() { return 'hello' }
const b = () => { return 'hello' }; //arrow Fn /w braces needs a return statement to return anything
const c = () => 'hello';            //shorthand arrow Fn w/o braces returns whatever the arrow points to
```

Here's a demo of this in action, using all the different function styles

```js
//regular function with no return value
var a = 'bar';
const myFunc1 = function() { a = 'foo'; }
console.log(myFunc1(), a);

//regular function with a return value
a = 'bar';
const myFunc2 = function() { return a = 'foo'; }
console.log(myFunc2(), a);

//arrow function with a return value
a = 'bar';
const myFunc3 = () => { return b = 'foo'; }
console.log(myFunc3(), a);

//arrow function with no return value
a = 'bar';
const myFunc4 = () => { b = 'foo'; }
console.log(myFunc4(), a);

//arrow function using shorthand, which has an implicit return value
a = 'bar';
const myFunc5 = () => b = 'foo';
console.log(myFunc5(), a);
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Although impossible to understand from the way I worded my question, I am actually aware of this. I should've included "when using the short-hand syntax"

Comment: With that in mind and re-reading your question I understand better.  it sounds like you want to use the shorthand syntax but you don't want the side effect that occur since they are now returning values.  I'd say... just don't do this.  The code will become very confusing if all functions now have a return value that nothing ever makes use of.  All it takes is one novice dev to misunderstand this and come to rely on the side-effects from this.

Comment: yeah I agree. Thanks again for the clarification, Chris.

Answer (score 2):

An assignment is just an expression, just as any other expression:

```
  const a = () => b = 1;

  console.log(
    c = 1,
    a()
  );
```

> without encountering any undesired behavior?

It depends if the caller expects something to be returned. If not, the returned result will go into nowhere, then it makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to clarify this. Cheers!